# L={a^nb^m| n+m=k ,n,m>=0} with Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want To generate the following language:

```
L={a^nb^m| n+m=k ,n,m>=0}
```

for a constant `k`.

I'm using the class `Regex` of namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

The best solution I have right now is:

```cs
public void Match(string input, int k)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"a*b*");
    Match match = regex.Match(input);
    if(match.Length==k)
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Don't match");
}
```

For `k=5` the following inputs are successfully:

```
"aaabb"
"aabbb"
"aaaaa"
```

This one for example is not:

```
"aaabbb"
"ab"
```

What's the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried http://regexhero.net/tester/ ? :)

Comment: @Live No, I use http://regexpal.com/ which is similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it using look aheads

For `k = 5`

```
/^(?=.{5}$)a*b*$/
```

- `(?=.{5}$)` Positve look ahead. Ensures that string contains only 5 characters.
- `a*b*` matches zero or more occurence of `a` followed by zero or more occurence `b`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aZ3aV4/1)

**Test**

```
public static void Match(string input, int k)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.{"+k+"}$)a*b*$");
    Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input));

}
```

---

```
Match("aaabb", 5);
=> True
Match("aaabbb", 5);
=> False
```

Answer (score 1):

nu11p01n73R's answer uses look-ahead, which is commonly used in practical regex, but is not part of theoretical regular expression (where concatenation, alternation, and Kleene stars are the only operators available).

There is no clean solution in theoretical regular expression for this case. You can only list all the cases. For example, if k = 5:

```
aaaaa|aaaab|aaabb|aabbb|abbbb|bbbbb
```

You can at most shorten it a bit by grouping:

```
aaa(aa|ab|bb)|(aa|ab|bb)bbb
```

The language is regular. `k` is a constant, so we can always draw a state machine with 2k + 1 states.

An example for k = 5:

[image]

Missing transitions goes to a trap state which is not an accepting state.

Comment: There is no reason to shorten it as any decent regex engine will setup the DFA exactly the same.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But I have a small doubt. But is  `L={a^nb^m| n+m=k ,n,m>=0}` a regular language at all. In theoritical regex we wont be able to keep track of the number of characters consumed. That is it how would we makes sure that `n+m=k`

Comment: The issue with this regex is that will only work for k=5. Can you suggest a way to make it work for any value of k?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: Since k is constant, it is a regular language. Due to finite k, the state machine has finite number of states.

Comment: @GuillermoAyranTorresLores: If you are looking for theoretical regular expression, no, there is no way to shorten it apart from grouping it like what I did. You can use nu11p01n73R's solution for practical purpose.

Comment: Your post reminded me the course "Computer Science 1" at university, and the glorious JFLAP. Thanks :)